# Contradicting constraint issues in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, layout, constraints

I have constraint issues that contradict: Xcode claims that my ScrollView is over-constraint and under-constraint at the same time.

See screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error message that might not be reporting "the missing constraint for: Y position or height" correctly.

The constraint conflict seems valid, because the scroll view is constrained to the top and bottom layout guides which have an inset that will be less than the height of the view controller view.  You can get rid of the conflict by removing the scroll View.height = height constraint.

Without seeing your view hierarchy setup, I want to guess that the "Need constraints for: Y position or height" is actually referring to the contents within the scroll view and its scrollable content area. Fully constraining the contents in the scroll view could resolve the missing constraint issue.